# SQL Batch Returning Different result to RPC

Tags: sql, batch-file, ssms

I have written a stored procedure that builds a string from a number of tables then returns it. It works perfectly from SSMS, the SP is called from  a third party piece of software where it is not returned the correct value.

The point of the SP is to generate an assettag of changes that have been made to a file. The sp is below

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_ACREpdflibTAG]
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @SJID INT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Asset VARCHAR(2000) 
    SET ANSI_NULLS OFF

SELECT @Asset = COALESCE(@Asset, '') + { fn CONCAT(tPdfChanges.ShortHand, '=1,') } 
FROM         tPdfChanges 
WHERE SubJobID = @SJID

DECLARE @AssetTag VARCHAR(4000)

```
SET @AssetTag = (SELECT 
'@@@AssetTagStart@@@' + 
@Asset
+ 'Desc=' + a.sName
+ ',UPC=' + h.sBarcodeStd
+ ',Cat=' + CAST(b.GACategoryID AS VARCHAR(10))
+ ',Type=' + CAST(d.GAProductTypeID AS VARCHAR(10))
+ ',PackFormat=' + CAST(f.GAPackTypeID AS VARCHAR(10))
+ ',DispDate=' + ISNULL(CONVERT ( varchar  , g.DCompleted ,105 ), '')
+ '@@@AssetTagEnd@@@'
FROM
tSubJob a   
WHERE
a.ID = @SJID)


select @AssetTag
END
```

I have had to remove the table names out of the query as they are sensitive to the business i am working for.

When it is run from SSMS, the following is returned:

```
@@@AssetTagStart@@@CutChg=1,DesChg=1,UPCChg=1,ProChg=1,IngChg=1,NutChg=1,StoreChg=1,CookChg=1,TtlChg=1,LegChg=1,AgyChg=1,WeightChg=1,CountryChg=1,ImpChg=1,OtherChg=1,Desc=Testing Triggers,UPC=,Cat=27,Type=3,PackFormat=38,DispDate=25-07-2012@@@AssetTagEnd@@@
```

When the third party piece of software executes it, the following is returned:

```
@@@AssetTagStart@@@CutChg=1,Desc=Testing Triggers,UPC=,Cat=27,Type=3,PackFormat=38,DispDate=25-07-2012@@@AssetTagEnd@@@
```

As you can see, it has only matched the one change in the first part of the asset tag.

I have used the profiler to see what is happening, when i execute it from SSMS, it is as an RPC, when it is executed from the third party software it is as a SQL Batch query.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

I have just solved this myself, I looked at the process ID in the profiler, looked further up and the thrid party software was setting the rowcount to 1, i reset this and it all worked perfectly.